# `undefined` assignable to the result of `Extract` operator with a discriminated union in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

I have a piece of code in TypeScript 3.9.2, the following is a minimal example showing the problem:

```js
type Cat =
  | { key: 'name', value: string }
  | { key: 'age', value: number }

function getProp<T extends Cat['key']>(key: T): Extract<Cat, { key: T, value: any }>['value'] {
  return undefined
}
```

As far as I understand, this piece of code should not compile. 
When calling `getProp`, `key: T` should either be `'name'` or `'age'`, which makes `Extract<Cat, { key: T, value: any }>` return either `{ key: 'name', value: string }` or `{ key: 'age', value: number }`.
Then the return value of `getProps` should be either `string` or `number`, depending on the argument `key`. `undefined` should not be assignable to it.

But to my surprise, it does compile.

I tried a few different things:

```js
type Cat =
  | { key: 'name', value: string }
  | { key: 'age', value: number }

// Doesn't compile, which is expected
function getProp1<T extends Cat['key']>(key: T): Extract<Cat, { key: T, value: any }> {
  return { value: undefined }
}

// Doesn't compile, which is expected
function getProp2<T extends Cat['key']>(key: T): Extract<Cat, { key: T, value: unknown }>['value'] {
  return undefined
}

// Compiles as expected.
function getProp3<T extends Cat['key']>(key: T): Extract<Cat, { key: T, value: unknown }>['value'] | undefined {
  return undefined
}
```

All three examples works (or doesn't work) as I expected.

Why does the original example works unexpectedly? Why using `unknown` and `any` makes a difference here?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a good question; I'm sure it will turn out to be some compiler assignability heuristic that is not technically type safe, but I'm having trouble figuring out which one it is.

Comment: Also, I assume `getProp2` should be returning `Extract<Cat, {key: T, value: unknown}>["value"]` instead of what you've got written down, right?

Comment: @jcalz My bad about the examples. Fixed it. I would guess it's some compiler assignability heuristic too, but I can't figure out which one either.